# JavaScript function to change div, based on option selected - doesn't always work as expected?

Tags: javascript, onchange, drop-down-menu

I have a JavaScript function (picture), which is activated when the visitor selects an option (onchange) from the drop down menu (picture_type), which then changes the data within the div (picture_div).

However not always does the data within the div reflect the chosen option, e.g: If you select the 'Select' option...then select the 'URL' option, the div doesn't reflect what should be their for the 'URL'.

Heres the JavaScript function along with the appropriate HTML:

```
<script>
function picture() {
    var picture_type = document.getElementById('picture_type').value;
    if (picture_type == 2) {
        document.getElementById('picture_div').innerHTML = '<a href="predefined_pics.php">Click here</a> to select one.';
    }
    if (picture_type >= 1) {
        document.getElementById('picture_div').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('picture_div').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>


<select id="picture_type" onchange="return picture();">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Upload</option>
<option value="1">URL</option>
<option value="2">Select</option>
</select>


<div id="picture_div" style="display: none;">
URL: <input name="url" type="text" style="width: 100%" />
</div>
```

If you don't understand me, I suggest you test the above code and play with the options to understand me better. :)

All help is greatly appreciated!.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code ,Try this out

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function picture() {
    var picture_type = document.getElementById('picture_type').value;
    if (picture_type == 2) {
        document.getElementById('picture_div').innerHTML = '<a href="predefined_pics.php">Click here</a> to select one.';
    }
    if(picture_type == 1) {
    document.getElementById('picture_div').innerHTML = 'URL: <input name="url" type="text" style="width: 100%" />';
    }
    if (picture_type >= 1) {
        document.getElementById('picture_div').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('picture_div').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="picture_type" onchange="return picture();">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Upload</option>
<option value="1">URL</option>
<option value="2">Select</option>
</select>


<div id="picture_div" style="display: none;">
URL: <input name="url" type="text" style="width: 100%" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

with regards,

**Wazzy**

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some inconsistencies in the code.

You are changing the contents of the `picture_div` only when the option `URL` is selected, but the div is displayed when either `URL` or `Select` is selected.

I think you need to change the value of the `picture_div` if the `Select` option is selected.

Actually what is the requirement here? Whether the `picture_div` has to be displayed while `URL` or `Select` options are selected? If that is the case then you have to check the condition

```
if (picture_type == 2) {
    document.getElementById('picture_div').innerHTML = '<a href="predefined_pics.php">Click here</a> to select one.';
}
```

because this condition handles only the `Select` case. You've to handle the case when the value is `1 (URL)` also.

Try this

```
function picture() {
    var picture_type = document.getElementById('picture_type').value;
    if (picture_type == 2) {
        document.getElementById('picture_div').innerHTML = '<a href="predefined_pics.php">Click here</a> to select one.';
    }else if(picture_type == 1){
        document.getElementById('picture_div').innerHTML = 'Option url';
    }
    if (picture_type >= 1) {
        document.getElementById('picture_div').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('picture_div').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```